# Three.js OrbitControls seems to break after returning to Chrome tab from another tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, tabs, camera

I'm not sure if the issue has something to do with how I've set things up in my application, some configuration issue with Chrome, the DOM, OrbitControls or another feature of Three.js.

When I load my application inside a tab in Chrome, everything works perfectly. When I change to another tab in Chrome, or minimize Chrome then return to it (I'm on a Windows machine), OrbitControls behavior changes. Notably, clicking on the left mouse button and moving the mouse around no longer orbits as before, but instead zooms out, up the Y-axis. It also appears like the camera-angle is suddenly a lot wider, and camera rotation center-point changes.

The only apparent fix is to reload the application in the tab, which works, but as I'm getting near alpha release on the product I'm starting to think about how users are not going to tolerate the issue as I have...

Here's what I believe to be my relevant code.

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init );

function init() {

    cameras();
    initRenderer();
    initEventListeners();
    entities();
    // Create the Stereoscopic viewing object (Not applied yet)
    var effect = new THREE.StereoEffect( renderer );

    render();         
}

function render() {

    renderer.render(scene, entities.cameras.perspCamera );

    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}

// if the device we're using has 'alpha' attribute, then it's a mixedReality-compatible mobile browser...
function setOrientationControls(e) {
    if (e.alpha) {
        initVRControls ();
    }
    else {
        initbrowserControls ();
        var camera = entities.cameras.perspCamera;
        entities.cameras.init( camera );
    }
}

function initbrowserControls() {

    // Create the Mouse-Based Controls - Hold down left mouse button and move around the window...

    var camera = entities.cameras.perspCamera;

    entities.browserControls = new THREE.OrbitControls ( camera , container );

    entities.browserControls.target.set(
        camera.position.x + 0.15,
        camera.position.y,
        camera.position.z
    );

    entities.browserControls.noPan = true;
    entities.browserControls.noZoom = true;
}

function initEventListeners() {

    // Listen for Device Orientation events.
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrientationControls, true);

}

function initRenderer() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.domElement.setAttribute( 'id' , 'renderSpace' );
    renderer.domElement.setAttribute( 'class' , 'threeWebGLRenderer' );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

};
```

if the code provided isn't sufficient to answer the question, let me know. I can provide what's needed. Thanks for the help!

---

UPDATE:

I've edited my code as suggested by @PerrinPrograms in the comments to try to reset the controls when `document.visibilityState` is reset to `"visible"`.

This seems a workaround... I'd rather get to the source of the problem, but thought following the tracks of it might provide more illumination.

The result is that the behavior is exactly the same, with the added bonus, as noted in the comments, that when I return to the application tab and have a console-break point at `setOrientationControls(e)` inside of my new `if` statement, I cannot restart the console action and have to reload the tab.

Here's what I did to my code:

```
function initEventListeners() {

    // Listen for Device Orientation events.
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrientationControls, true);
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', onDocumentVisible, true); // ADDED LINE

}

// ADDED FUNCTION
function onDocumentVisible(e){

    if ( document.visibilityState === "visible" ){ // CONSOLE LOCKS UP IF I PLACE BREAK HERE
        setOrientationControls(e);  // HERE TOO
    }
}
```

The plot thickens... Thanks all for looking into this with me.

Comment: what happens when using firefox or edge?

Comment: It seems you're not calling `initbrowserControls()` at any point in your code above. Can you put your code in a JSFiddle so others can more easily try to debug in Chrome?

Comment: @Marquizzo `initbrowserControls()` is called in 'setOrientationControls()` nevertheless setting up a JSFiddle is a good idea. I'll get that going in a bit and will update here.

Comment: @PerrinPrograms the controls don't work at all in FF or Edge. I was thinking that might be a separate issue, but if I can kill 2 birds with one stone, awesome.

Comment: There's an api for HTML5 to check if the a browser tab is minimized or not visible and maybe you could reinitialize or reset the controls when making the page visible again?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API I'm not sure what your problem is exactly but I'd also be curious to use your Jsfiddle to see if it's just your problem or everyone's problem.

Comment: I'm trying to get the JSFiddle working but cannot, though running the code in the JSFiddle works fine in Chrome from Node in my local machine. http://jsfiddle.net/markscottlavin/to6mdw9x/70/. Alternatively, you can look at the following: http://experiments.vertecology.com/lucidchart/ ... this is a different experiment of mine that's live online but the issue is the same. And the code for this is up on GitHub. Relevant file: https://github.com/MarkScottLavin/LucidChart/blob/master/app.js, relevant code starts on line 661. I hope this is useful...

Comment: @PerrinPrograms I just attempted the suggested Page_Visibility_API solution. The behavior is exactly the same, except for one thing. When I go back to my app from another tab I'm now capturing the visibilityChange event. When the `document.visibilityState === "visible"` verifies `true`, I run `setOrientationControls(e)` as when the document first loads.  When I have a breakpoint in the console set at at the point where I run `setOrientationControls(e)` from inside the `if` statement, I can't restart the action in the console. That tells me something's wrong. Updating the code momentarily.